# how can we track mouse events in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

We are trying to use the highcharts renderer library to draw custom shapes like line and arc on the charts we were able to access the starting x and y coordinates via "`chart.container.onmousedown`" event and end x and y coordinates via "`chart.container.onmouseup`"

the method is working in Chrome and Mozilla, but giving problem in IE for chart.renderer method

We are successfully using the "chart.renderer.arc" and "chart.renderer.path" in chrome and Mozilla. But not in IE

found similar problem  in the link http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=10271

but the solution suggested not working for us.

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: for the reference i put a demo at http://transpacificsoftware.in/demo/highcharts/

Comment: Which version of highcharts are you using? If you are using anything before version 2, you'll need to include another library to render elements in IE.